# Axis tick label alignment for host_subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

In creating a graph with multiple vertical axes (along the lines of http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html) I'm trying to rotate the labels on the horizontal axis. However, the code that is supposed to do that doesn't seem to do anything.

For example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_sub_axes = 3

host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=max(0.75, 1-0.075*num_sub_axes))
host.axis["left"].toggle(all=False)

for sub_ax_idx in range(num_sub_axes):
    new_ax = host.twinx()

    new_fixed_axis = new_ax.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
    new_ax.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right", axes=new_ax, offset=(45 * sub_ax_idx, 0))
    new_ax.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)

    line, = new_ax.plot([0, 1, 2], [(sub_ax_idx+1)**2, (sub_ax_idx+1)**2.5, (sub_ax_idx+1)**3], label=str(sub_ax_idx))

    new_ax.axis["right"].label.set_color(line.get_color())
    new_ax.axis["right"].major_ticklabels.set_color(line.get_color())
    new_ax.axis["right"].minor_ticklabels.set_color(line.get_color())

host.set_xticks([0, 1, 2])
host.set_xticklabels(["One", "Two", "Three"], rotation=-45, horizontalalignment="right", verticalalignment="bottom")

host.legend()
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

This creates a graph like the following:
[image: example graph]

Note that the horizontal labels ("One", "Two", "Three") are plainly horizontal, even though I used the `rotation=-45` keyword argument in my call to `set_xticklabels` as specified in the documentation: http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html

I suspect this may have to do with the fact that this isn't just a regular `axes` object.

But if not as in above, how do I rotate these labels?

Comment: I'm sure just looking at the docs isn't going to rotate my labels. :)
That said, I don't immediately see how to do what I want to do from the docs either. Post some sample code maybe?

Comment: What I should have said is yes, it is because it is not a standard `Axes` object so you have to look at the docs for the specific subclass. The relevant section was linked in my comment. Unfortunately I did not have time to write a complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the axes are not normal axes anymore but axes within an [axisartist container](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/axisartist.html#axisartist-namespace). As has been pointed out by Goyo in an encrpyted comment, this container's methods may differ from the normal axes methods.

In this case, for setting the rotation of the major ticklabels you need

```
host.axis["bottom"].major_ticklabels.set_rotation(-45)
```